# Is there a PDF viewer for Linux that supports filling out forms?

Tags: linux, pdf-viewer, forms

I'm looking for a PDF viewer for Linux that I can use to fill out PDF forms and save them as a file.

Happy for suggestions!

Answer (score 3):

[Okular](https://okular.kde.org/) 0.24.2 is able to handle forms.

Answer (score 3):

In Linux the default pdf viewer(in ubuntu) [evince](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Evince) can view a pdf with forms and also allow you to fill up the forms. Although the experience is not that pleasant.

[Okular](https://okular.kde.org/) can handle forms preety well. My experience with it is really good. Although it does not allow you to add signature from an image file or to create a pdf with forms.

Finally, [Libreoffice Draw](https://www.libreoffice.org/discover/draw/) which is preinstalled in most of the linux distros is an awesome application. It allows you to edit pdfs even those that are not forms. You can add custom text, image etc in a pdf and save it. Also it allows you to create a pdf with forms.

Answer (score 2):

[qpdfview 0.4.18](https://pkgs.org/download/qpdfview) is able to do too.

Answer (score 2):

[mupdf-gl](https://mupdf.com/docs/manual-mupdf-gl.html) which is minimalist/lightweight, can handle forms and annotations.

Press F1 for keyboard shortcuts.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I use Chromium.  Its built in PDF viewer allows the filling of a form and then you can save it to disc either filled out, or as an unfilled form.  For completing forms, I find it the most intuitive and it is familiar to what I do when on my Windows machine.  Not so sure about its ability to sign a PDF form though.

Comment: Welcome Halvo! Would you mind adding a link to your recommendation within your answer?  Thanks, and again, welcome.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the default Ubuntu PDF viewer - [evince](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Evince).

1. Fill the form
2. Print (CTRL + P)
3. Print to file

[image: press print or ctrl + p]
[image: choose 'print to file' option]